# Javascript (jQuery) events failing. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-propagation

This (jQuery) function is invoked on `jQuery(document).ready` and `jQuery(document).resize`. It runs fine on the `ready` condition but on `resize` the events go a bit screwy. They either inherit functionality or in the case of the slideToggle seemingly fire for each resize.

```
(function(jQuery){
    jQuery.fn.responsive = function() {
        // Vars
        var menuButton = jQuery('nav #menu-button');
        var menuItems = jQuery('nav ul');
        var menuLinks = jQuery('nav ul li a.scroll');
        var viewportW = jQuery(window).width(); 
        var viewportH = jQuery(window).height();  
        // Menu links
        menuLinks.click(function(e){
            if (viewportW > 800) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                var pos = jQuery(this.hash).offset().top;
                jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
            } else if (viewportW < 799) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                menuItems.slideUp('fast'); // Hide menu on click
            }
        });
        // Menu button
        menuButton.click(function(e){
            menuItems.slideToggle('fast');
            //e.stopPropagation();
            //e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to kill event propagation but to no avail.

EDIT:

This runs after:

```
// Doc ready
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Run functions
    jQuery().responsive();
});


// On resize
jQuery(window).resize(function(){  
    jQuery().responsive();
});
```

Comment: I can't see .resize() in the code.

Comment: Are you really trying to kill ready and/or resize events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call one of the callback registation functions likes `$(someElement).click(...)`, you are actually *adding* a handler for that event.  If you call the function twice with the same, the handler gets called twice.  Do demonstrate, try this html page (with jquery.js in the same page):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function addhook() {
        $("div").click(function(e) {
            console.info("click!");
            $("body").append($("<div>click!</div>"));
            return false;
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        addhook();
        $(window).resize(addhook);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><a href="#">Click me</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On first loading the page, it behaves as expected, but then after resizing the window, clicking "Click me" gets more than one "click!".

The only reason you would have for re-registering a handler is if the respective elements have been destroyed and re-created.

If this is happening, and it's not convenient to attempt to reliably re-register the handlers when necessary, consider using [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Also note the [.off() function](http://api.jquery.com/off/) which can remove all of the handlers on a set of elements.

Lastly, you should probably change

```
jQuery.fn.responsive = function() {
```

to

```
jQuery.responsive = function() {
```

adding to `jQuery.fn` adds functions that can be called from jQuery objects, i.e. allowing, say,

```
$("div").responsive();
```

For some reason these functions are also added to the `jQuery` object itself, so it still works, but the latter makes the function's purpose more clear and keeps the jQuery class clean.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Very generous explanation! I thank you for the last tip and your explanation makes muddy waters somewhat clearer. I am going to follow those links and see if I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i misunderstand you question before.

as i see,it's no need to eval **$.responsive()** every resize.

just

```
$.fn.responsive = function(){
    //Vars
    var menuButton = $('nav #menu-button');
    var menuItems = $('nav ul');
    var menuLinks = $('nav ul li a.scroll');
    //Menu links
    menuLinks.click(function(event){
        //**move width&height inside
        var viewportW = $(window).width(); 
        var viewportH = $(window).height();
        if(viewportW > 800){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            var pos = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
        }else if(viewportW < 799){
            event.stopPropagation();
            menuItems.slideUp('fast');// Hide menu on click
        }
    });
    //Menu button
    menuButton.click(function(event){
        menuItems.slideToggle('fast');
        //event.stopPropagation();
        //event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //just once
    $.fn.responsive();
});
```

Comment: This prints "resize" to console. Did you mean to run my function within `resize`? What is the thinking behind this?

Comment: @NielsOeltjen get current width&height every click,not resize